# Simplifying factorial with different coefficient

Tags: factorial

$$\frac{(pn)!}{(qn)!},\quad p\not = q$$

If possible, how could I simplify the above factorial?

Comment: You could maybe use the Gamma function? $\frac{Γ(n p + 1)}{Γ(n q + 1)}$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an exact calculation, I suggest, just as @Reety commented, to write
$$A=\frac{(pn)!}{(qn)!}=\frac{\Gamma( pn + 1)}{\Gamma( qn + 1)}\implies \log(A)=\log (\Gamma (n p+1))-\log (\Gamma (n q+1))$$ and use the  $\text{log$\Gamma $}(x)$ function which is available almost in any computing environment [Excel has it; it is GAMMALN( x )]. An then, for sure $A=e^{\log(A)}$.

If you want an approximate value, as Ross Millikan answered, Stirling approximation is the most convenient
$$\log(A)\approx(p-q) n (\log (n)-1) + (p \log (p)-q \log (q))n+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)+\frac{q-p}{12  p q}\frac 1n+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ In these forms, $p$ and $q$ do not require to be integer numbers.

Trying with $n=100$, $p=\pi$, $q=e$, the approximation would give $A=2.75535890270\times 10^{104}$ while the exact value is     $2.75535890283\times 10^{104}$

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) may be of help.  Here it gives
$$\frac {(pn)!}{(qn)!}\approx \frac{(pn)^{pn}}{(qn)^{qn}}e^{(q-p)n}\sqrt{\frac pq}$$